# Using an app API that requires facebook auth

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'd like my website to be able to make API calls to replace a mobile app which uses Facebook for auth. Users would sign in with Facebook just like they do for the app, and then instead of the app sending API calls, my server would be doing it.

If I want to send requests for my account, it's easy, I just generate an auth token on behalf of that app by accessing

> facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id_here&redirect_uri=facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

and find the access token in the 'location' field of the response.

For my website to do it though, I need to be able to access other people's generated auth tokens, ie open a dialog with a URL like

> facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id_here&redirect_uri=my.website

This doesn't work because the app is configured not to allow it:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I can't do it on the client side either because of cross origin policy:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load facebook.com/dialog/oauth?... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any way to do this besides a chrome extension which would be allowed to do cross origin requests?

P.S. all https:// intentionally redacted because not enough reputation.

Comment: All you have to do is fix your app settings, so that the “Given URL is not allowed by …” message goes away. (And that error has been discussed countless times already – so do some proper research please.) // And you can of course not call the login dialog via AJAX – it has to be called in the top window instance, so that users can verify via the address bar that they are not on a phishing site.

Comment: It's not my app. I guess I forgot to make that clear. I'd like to make a web client for a third-party app.

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your app dashboard and configure your given URL to access your Facebook app.